# AWS Amplify separate environments (DEV / PROD)

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify, environment

I developed a mobile app using react-native and AWS Amplify. I developed Amplify in Staging environment, and react-native used react-native-config to separate dev/prod environment.

I added prod environment in Amplify Console.

Question 1. Auth, S3 bucket, Functions, API, etc. were all replicated in prod, but the Data model was not. Do I have to rewrite this by hand?

Question 2. I want to apply Amplify's staging / prod environment separately when building the react-native code. I want to make sure that the Amplify staging environment is applied when building the react-native to dev, and the prod environment is applied when building to prod. If I run the 'amplify env list' command, only staging will be output as below.

```
| | Environments |
| ------------ |
| | *staging |
```

If anyone has solutions, I'd greatly appreciate detailed explanations.
Thanks.